# PowerBi How to extract characters from a column into 3 columns

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

how are you all doing?

I need some help with the data im working on, I'm trying to breakdown a column into three new columns on PowerBI

[image]

Conditions

1. if the characters starts with a Letter, it moves to the Left, else leave it blank
2. If the character ends with a W, then move it to the Right
3. extract the numbers in between
4. get rid of the '%'

[image: Sample of Actual Dataset]

Comment: Please provide sample data (markdown table) or is this to be done in Photoshop?

Comment: @Peter I added a sample of the actual Dataset

Comment: null=Blank() in all columns?

Comment: And did any of our answers help you out?

Answer (score 0):

The following changes this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Score", type text}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type","%","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Score"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value", "Left", each if [Score] <> null then let check = try Number.From(Text.At([Score],0)) in if check[HasError] then Text.At([Score],0) else "" else ""),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Actual %", each if [Score] <> null then Text.Select([Score],{"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","."}) else ""),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Right", each if [Score] <> null then let check = try Number.From(Text.At([Score],Text.Length([Score])-1)) in if check[HasError] then Text.At([Score],Text.Length([Score])-1) else "" else "")
in
    #"Added Custom2"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Left", each if Value.Is(Value.FromText(Text.Start([Column1],1)), type text) then Text.Start([Column1],1) else null),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Right", each if Text.Upper(Text.End([Column1],1))= "W" then "W" else null),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Actual%", each Text.Select([Column1],{Character.FromNumber(46),Character.FromNumber(48)..Character.FromNumber(57) } ))
in #"Added Custom2"
```

| Column1 |
| --- |
| D86W |
| A45 |
| A88W |
| 88W |
| 88% |
| A85W |
| A66 |
| 70W |
| 99% |
| 88 |
| 89W |
| D86W |